# .htaccess file RewriteRule appends %25s to URL creating 404 errors

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

Last year I changed the permalink structure on a Wordpress blog. It didn't seem to cause any issues, old URLs had a permanent 301 redirect.

After running a Moz site crawl though, I noticed a collection of 404 errors. The original links are still redirecting to the new links, but Moz detected that %25s is being appended to both the old and new URLs, creating these errors.

[image]

I'm assuming this is a problem with my rewrite rules, but I am not sure where. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/(.*) https://letsprint3d.net/$4 [R=301,L]

### bunch of LiteSpeed Cache lines ###

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: did u find any explanation where did this %25s came from?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following rule to remove the trailing `%25s` from your URLs . Just put at the top of your htaccess or before WordPress rules.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^%25s]+)/\%25s
RewriteRule .+ https://example.com/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, is it? The question asked where that "%25s" comes from and how to prevent it. Not how to accept it and removed it again later.